# Access Auth component in Model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to create a Behavior to automagically populate a 'created_by' field when a record gets saved with the id of the logged in user, much like timestamp does with 'created'.  However, apparently you can get $this->Auth->user('id') everywhere *except* in the Model.

I am having to resort to updating the request data in the controller's add() method before the save() call, which works but it's not DRY.  I'd like to have bake add the behavior in a model's table class for any entity that has a 'created_by' field.

Any ideas how I could do this in a Behavior, the way Cake intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Blame](https://github.com/ceeram/blame) behavior does what you need. You can either use it or study it's code to implement your own.

Comment: There is a difference though: the Blame behavior seems to work only for models loaded in controllers directly. Thus it doesn't work for instance on linked models.

Comment: Blame has since been deprecated, [UseMuffin /
Footprint](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint) appears to have picked up the torch.  The approach used there  is to create a [Trait](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint/blob/master/src/Auth/FootprintAwareTrait.php)  with a [behaviour](https://github.com/UseMuffin/Footprint/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/FootprintBehavior.php).

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to use the Events System. I personaly did this by using a `Component` and a `Behavior` that communicate through the `Model.beforeSave` event. Basically the component is responsible to add a new listener that passes a function to the behavior allowing to retrieve the authenticated user id.

You can have a look at the code of both classes here: [UserLinkComponent](https://github.com/alaxos/cakephp3-libs/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/UserLinkComponent.php), [UserLinkBehavior](https://github.com/alaxos/cakephp3-libs/blob/master/src/Model/Behavior/UserLinkBehavior.php)

and to use them:

Controller:

```
$this->loadComponent('Alaxos.UserLink');
```

Model\Table:

```
$this->addBehavior('Alaxos.UserLink');
```